# Sargability question - order of variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, query-performance

I have a stored procedure that has a few lines:

```
AND ( @StartDate IS NULL OR @StartDate <= r.ReferralDate )
AND ( @EndDate IS NULL OR @EndDate >= r.ReferralDate )
```

Should it be re-written as:

```
AND ( r.ReferralDate >= @StartDate or @Startdate IS NULL  )
AND ( r.ReferralDate <= @EndDate or @EndDate IS NULL )
```

I tried it both ways and looking at the execution plans. There is a small difference in estimated number of rows, but other than that I do not see a change, so I assumed that the order in the statement did not matter, but was hoping someone could verify.

Comment: If you add a [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) we can go deeper, but in this case the order won't affect the sargability - as you seem to already have known. If you're curious about other differences between the two, you'll need to provide a more complete example and may want to more accurately describe what your question is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that the order you put these in makes no difference to SARGability. If you want this to be as efficient as possible, you can add a RECOMPILE hint, or use dynamic SQL to generate the appropriate WHERE clause.

Since you seem to understand the concepts involved, I won't beat any dead horses here, I'll just point you to a great source on the subject: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)